# how to pass object from one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an library app which has two models `Book` and `Suggestion`. The `Suggestion` model is used to suggest books to be added to the library.

Now in the `Suggestion` model, I have added a method to retrieve the book and I wish to add this book into the database.

The Code for the above are as follows:

**Suggestion.rb**

```
def get_book
        h = as_json
        h.delete("id")
        h.delete("created_at")
        h.delete("updated_at")
        return Book.new(h)
    end
```

**SuggestionController.rb**

```
def approve
@book = @suggestion.get_book
    redirect_to @book, notice: "Book was successfully added into the database"
```

But since the `@book` has not been assigned the `id`, it is not able to redirect it.

All the other controllers and models are initiated via scaffolding.

How should I retain the information contained in the suggestion and pass it to book controller to add into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to new book instead newly created. New book properties You can pass via `redirect_to`, for example:

```
redirect_to new_book_path, notice: "Book was successfully added into the database", new_book: @book.to_json
```

And check `new_book` parameter in `new` method:

```
def new
    if params[:new_book].nil?
        # usual behavior
    else
        @book = Book.new(params[:new_book])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

not really related, but want to help you to have more effective code.

istead of

```
def get_book
    h = as_json
    h.delete("id")
    h.delete("created_at")
    h.delete("updated_at")
    return Book.new(h)
end
```

you can write

```
def get_book
  Book.new as_json.except(*[:id, :created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

and just for the record: please dont use `@var` in controllers if you are just redirecting. only use `@var` if you use them inside a template.

have a nice day!